# TypeError: x is read-only when trying to reassign in multidensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reassign a value at x index in a multidimensional array, and I get the error in the title. Here is my code:

```
  var str  = "SERR PBQR PNZC";
  var arr = str.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){ 
  for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length;j++){
     arr[i][j] = String.charCodeAt((arr[i][j]) - 13);
   }
  }
```

Any help is appreciated thanks! My apologies for lack of information the first time, i am scatterbrained at this point

Comment: can we see the arrays?

Comment: please add `str` and `arr`. you may have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the error unclear? Where is `x` in your example? What is the code supposed to do? What is the input? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

An assignment to a multi-dimensional array is not happening. An assignment to a string at a specific index is happening. Strings are immutable—they can't be assigned to—so you can't do that.

Basically what's happening is the following:

```
var arr = "SERR PBQR PNZC".split(" ");
var str = arr[0]; // "SERR", this is a string
str[0] = "o";     // doesn't work, can't assign to string at an index
```

You'll need to change your code with that in mind. Perhaps you meant to work with the `numbers` array?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```js
var str = "Hello World";

var arr = str.split(" ");
var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  numbers[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    numbers[i][j] = arr[i].charCodeAt(j) - 13;
  }
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.charCodeAt()` is a method on Strings, not a stand-alone utility function.  You want `arr[i].charCodeAt(j)` or even `arr[i][j].charCodeAt()` (because it returns the character code of a single character).

Also, you need to fix your parenthesis - you're trying to subtract 13 from string rather than subtracting 13 from your character code.